# Prohibitively slow insert performance on aws RDS micro

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm running a free RDS instance on AWS and I'm trying to run some very simple query to insert about 10000 rows. I followed this guide

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html

to do the insert properly and not use the ORM (use Core), but it is *incredibly* slow. Here is my very simple code inserting dummy data:

```
from models import Transaction
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import time

db_string = 'connection_string'
engine = create_engine(db_string)
all_txs_flat = []

for i in range(0, 10000):
    all_txs_flat.append(
        Transaction(token='test', block_number=1000, from_address='qfieieoqfieqnfioeqnfioqenfiodnvd', to_address='cqkwiofjeqiojqnvoienvioeqnvvnksvvwe',
                         amount=5000))

t0 = time.time()
engine.execute(
    Transaction.__table__.insert(),
    [{"token": tx.token, "block_number": tx.block_number, "from_address": tx.from_address,
      "to_address": tx.to_address, "amount": tx.amount} for tx in
     all_txs_flat]
)
print(
    "SQLAlchemy Core: Total time for " + str(10000) +
    " records " + str(time.time() - t0) + " secs")
```

It is a straight out of the box config for the RDS. Just followed the wizard and opened up 5432 to my IP so I could connect on my local machine. The output is alarming...

`SQLAlchemy Core: Total time for 10000 records 360.06809306144714 secs`

Am I missing something obvious? What can I do to profile this? I don't believe I am running into the t2.micro limits here.

Thanks

Comment: Is this code running in EC2 or on a machine that is local to you?

Comment: Local! I think that might be it!